# Notepad++ new keywords defined with regex for the Styler configuration

Tags: regex, notepad++, syntax-highlighting, keyword, scintilla

If I want to add new keywords in the Styler configuration for the "c" language suppose, and I have my custom defined data type. for eg:

```
uint_8 a;
uint_16 b;
uint_32 c;
uint_12bla bla;*
```

is it possible to add somehow the keywords, instead of adding explictly harcoding each keywords,
as a regex, **(uint_\d+\w*)** ?

mostly benifitted, incase I have thousands of intrinsics starting with naming format and I want to highlight all of them.
eg:

```
vector_intrinsic_add(a,b);
vector_intrinsic_mul(a,b);
vector_intrinsic_shit_right(a,b);
vector_intrinsic_shift_left(a,b);
vector_intrinsic_fill_zero(a);
vector_intrinsic_do_bla(a,b);
```

Comment: No, I'm 99% sure that this isn't possible.

Comment: I hope, even if I create a userdefined language, with nearly thousand keywords, this will not make noticable downgrade in the speed of the editing (not getting Stuck often or hugh RAM usage).
(I just asummed that, it makes a constant parsing of the input text on the editor window to display the configured color immediately)

Comment: I never tried this, but I wouldn't expect a considerable speed downgrade. Let us know how it actually worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Styler configurator, you can declare a keyword "group" to have the "Prefix" property. That means that the patterns which match the group will still be colored if they have extra text following them.

If you're fairly confident that anything starting with uint_|vector_intrinsic_ should be highlighted, then go ahead and allocate a group for that purpose. Beware that you only get 4 groups, so you may need to shuffle some keywords around to get the configuration you want.

Source: http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/languages/user-defined-languages

Comment: Sadly, that link seems dead.  Until a better one comes along, try this one: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Languages

Comment: @JesseChisholm Sadly also dead nowadays :).